# Are hydrogen bonds between two hydroxyl groups stronger if one is deprotonated?

Tags: hydrogen-bond

Hydrogen bonds can form between two hydroxyl groups. Is the hydrogen bond stronger if one of the groups is deprotonated?

[image]

Comment: Yes, if the one on the left is deprotonated, the hydrogen bond shown will be stronger. The opposite is true for the one on the right.

Comment: Thanks. Ah I managed to read up on that, or, understand it since it was pretty easy. The one on the right, if it is deprotonated, that would prevent any bond forming at all with it as the donor, right? Since it can't donate much anymore.

Comment: @KarstenTheis An interesting observation. The deprotonated group, it has, relatively speaking, less negative charge. Otherwise, it would be able to hold onto the proton just as well. And since the hydrogen bond acceptor is the group with most negative charge, the deprotonated one would only be favoured because it lacks the proton, not because is has less negative charge in itself.

Comment: @NilayGhosh I'm actually looking at the issue from a very unusual angle. So my complete self-answer would include it. The thing is, I think that, if introduced in a "lock and key" setting with a specific type of fit, the deprotonated group might actually be the hydrogen bond donor. This is very counter-intuitive, but, it relies on the groups being forced close to each other to start with. Then, the combined negative charge of the groups, will actually protonate the deprotonated group, and it will be the donor the the more negatively charged other group.

Comment: @NilayGhosh What I did was I wrote the answer that was the one I was looking for (plus the simple answer Karsten gave. ) I think it is factually correct. What it lacks is context, but, I know the context already, it just takes a bit of time to communicate it so I left it out. So in this context, I just require it is factually correct even if the scenario seems far fetched, and it seems right to me. It also points people to the fact that the deprotonated group is actually deprotonated because it is "relatively speaking" "less negative", an interesting observation.

Comment: The image in the question suggests that the hydroxyl groups would align parallel, which is of course not the case. If you remove a proton from the system (whether or not and how this might be done is another question) you'll have a system, in which dynamic effect will be very important. See the [Grotthuss mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotthuss_mechanism). So whether or not the bond can be considered "stronger" is highly debatable and depends on the point of vie you would like to take.

Comment: To show appreciation to @ KarstenTheis and @NilayGhosh who were both kind and polite. My exact discovery, is that ATP binds the p-loop region in a way where ATP is actually fully protonated. The exact relevance of this, can be understood by catching up with the last decade of advances in biology and the physics of what happens to water at surfaces. Here is a publication of an overview of what I've discovered. If that is "forbidden" to share then delete away I guess, I am not in control of what "Martin" or anyone else does in their "kingdom" here. https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.5225148

Comment: Others - including me, who actually published on the mechanism of ATP hydrolysis in the p-loop region (you're leaving out switches 1 and 2) of myosin - have demonstrated that ATP is far from fully protonated (experiment and theory). In addition to your aggressive tone, you're convinced you're right. The combination is not a good one.